# Unix socket communication how to see the relationship of the nodes

Tags: networking

In Linux, I could use ss or netstat -anp command to see TCP and Unix communication. In TCP communication, I could see localIP, Local port, Peer IP and Peer port. What's more, I could see PID and program name. But when I see netstat -anp with Unix part, I could not identify the peer IP. I know Unix does not use port. But it shall shows Peer IP in some linux commands.

```
[k8s@k8s config]$ netstat -anp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9099          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10251         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     100174318 -                    @/containerd-shim/moby/ebde2be0a20ea82431e38a9af5222540ad86a3049a7896646273783e8e5616dd/shim.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     95532948 -                    @/containerd-shim/moby/d02dca7b9146fb4cbca3eb26f0a666b5999922c7803d81b28281d9604bb32249/shim.sock
```

The linux command netstat -anp's output is shown above. With Unix part, I could not identify Peer IP. I am doing network service topology diagram for this purpose.

Comment: Unix domain sockets don't have an IP address. They have a file path instead and work only locally. Read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket for example.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @terdon CentOS 7.4, but we concern Ubuntu, CentOS，and other major Linux version at this moment. In future, we will consider Solaris。